# What is wrong with this nested for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, nested, nested-loops

I cannot for the life of me work out why this nested for loop isn't working.

```
public void getMagsAboveX(double minimumMag)
{
    for(Observatory myObservatory : monitoring) {
        for(Earthquake myEarthquake : earthquakes) {
            if(myEarthquake.returnMagnitude() > minimumMag) {
                System.out.print(myEarthquake.returnMagnitude() + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error "cannot find symbol - variable earthquakes" but as far as I know earthquakes is the name of the second ArrayList I want to iterate through. If I change 'earthquakes' to ArrayList() I get the error "-> expected". I don't know what it doesn't like.

Comment: Which line of code fails and with which error?

Comment: Good tradition in Java is not using simple word 'variable', but 'field', 'local variable', 'static field', 'parameter' etc ...  word have meaning, wrong use give misuderstanding

Comment: A user of a  `get...` method expects that something is given to him and not that it's `void`. Your `get...` method produces a side effect.

Comment: Your `list...` method has a parameter `minimumMag`. However, you say you want the value by user input.

Comment: @Smutje for example if I try doing:
    public void listMagsAboveX(double minimumMag)
    {
        for(Observatory myObservatory : monitoring) {
            System.out.print(myObservatory.getMagsAboveX(minimumMag) + ", ");
        }
    }
myObservatory.getMagsAboveX(minimumMag) fails with the error 'void' type not allowed here

Comment: Please edit your post to add the code. Don't post codes in the comments

Comment: @ThomasWeller yeah I meant minimumMag is a user-entered parameter. I then want the value of that parameter to be passed to getMagsAboveX when that method is called. apologies if I'm unclear, still getting my head around all the terminology!

Comment: @ThomasWeller will have a look at that. thanks

Comment: @ThomasWeller new problem but stackoverflow won't let me create a new question. can you help or direct me to an appropriate existing thread? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

First : in your javadoc comments to your methods you say that your methods "return" something. They don't though. Both methods are `void`.

And as long as you call `getMagsAboveX(minimumMag)` on an object of type Observatory inside your `listMagsAboveX` method, I don't see what could fail.

You should post the full methods if you want more help though.